# Audio bytes chunks getting corrupted during streaming using Django and Websockets

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to implement an audio streaming transcription service using django and websockets. The implementation works but the chunks get corrupted after some time like after tenth or eleventh chunk of transcription, while debugging, I discovered that the webm audio bytes extension was missing (which means some other metadata might also be missing in those chunks which makes me unable to transcribe those chunks.

```
class TranscriptConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    """
    Server side implementation of the audio streaming service
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.audio_buffer = b''  # Variable to store accumulated audio data
```

I used the audio_buffer variable to concatenate all audio bytes chunks still in an effort to prevent the corruption of data because before using that variable to concatenate the chunks, I experienced the audio bytes corruption after the first chunk. I use below to receive and concatenate the chunks

```
async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        if bytes_data:
            # Combine incoming bytes_data with the accumulated audio_buffer
            self.audio_buffer += bytes_data

            # Check if the combined data is sufficient for processing
            if len(self.audio_buffer) >= 10000:  
                await self.process_audio()
```

And below to transcribe the chunks

```
# Split the combined data into chunks
max_chunk_size = 1024 * 1024  # 1MB chunk size
chunks = [self.audio_buffer[i:i + max_chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(self.audio_buffer), max_chunk_size)]
           

# Process chunks in parallel (using asyncio.gather for concurrency)
tasks = [self.transcribe_chunk(chunk, model) for chunk in chunks]
transcriptions = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

when the chunk is not corrupted, I get "Audio format Server Side: ['webm']" but when it is corrupted, I get "Audio format Server Side: None"

Comment: I already fixed this, I adjusted the implementation in the client side to treat each chunk as a separate audio file (audio bytes with corresponding extension and metadata) as opposed to treating the entire chunks as a single audio file splitted into bytes which I implemented initially